# Three combo boxes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have 3 combo boxes with the same 3 selections in each. If the user picks the same selection a 2nd time, the first combo box resets. I have 3 other sections that will do the same with about 15 combo boxes.

Is there a shorter/compact way to code what I'm doing?

```
Protected Sub ComBox_GER1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComBox_GER1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim ValueSelected = ComBox_GER1.SelectedIndex

    If ComBox_GER2.SelectedIndex = ValueSelected Then
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        ComBox_GER2.ClearSelection()
    End If
    If ComBox_GER3.SelectedIndex = ValueSelected Then
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        ComBox_GER3.ClearSelection()
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub ComBox_GER2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComBox_GER2.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim ValueSelected = ComBox_GER2.SelectedIndex

    If ComBox_GER1.SelectedIndex = ValueSelected Then
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        ComBox_GER1.ClearSelection()
    End If
    If ComBox_GER3.SelectedIndex = ValueSelected Then
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        ComBox_GER3.ClearSelection()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub ComBox_GER3_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComBox_GER3.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim ValueSelected = ComBox_GER3.SelectedIndex

    If ComBox_GER1.SelectedIndex = ValueSelected Then
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        ComBox_GER1.ClearSelection()
    End If
    If ComBox_GER2.SelectedIndex = ValueSelected Then
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        ComBox_GER2.ClearSelection()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `Thread.Sleep` calls. All of them. You don't need them. If two comboboxes have that value it's a **whole second** you're sleeping for no reason. ASP.NET event handlers *run on the server side*, which means the user is going to be waiting longer than he needs to, to get a response back from your code.

Now for your handlers you'll have to be careful about the *[Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)* sequence of events; I don't do ASP.NET very often (read: never) but I *think* you'll want to register your event handlers in the Page_Load handler. You'll want to register a handler per "section", not per combobox.

I'd make a method that takes a `ComboBox` instance and an `IEnumerable<ComboBox>`, and compares the values of the `ComboBox` with that of each item in the `IEnumerable<ComboBox>` (just realized that's the C# notation for generics.. make that `(Of ComboBox)`) *that is not the same reference than `ComboBox`*, and clear selection if the values match.

```
Private Sub ClearDuplicateSelections(comboBox As ComboBox, comboBoxes As IEnumerable(Of ComboBox))
    For Each cb In comboBoxes
        If Not cb.Equals(comboBox) Then 'there is a better way to do this but I don't VB much
            If cb.SelectedIndex = comboBox.SelectedIndex Then cb.ClearSelection()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Now all you need is to pass the method a combobox (the "sender") and all the comboboxes in the same "group" or "section". In C# I'd do it like this:

```cs
// cast the sender from Object to ComboBox:
var box = (ComboBox)sender; 

// put all comboboxes of that section in an array:
var boxes = new[] { ComBox_GER1, ComBox_GER2, ComBox_GER3 }; 

ClearDuplicateSelections(box, boxes);
```

---

Side note, be careful with naming: `ValueSelected` is lying - it represents the selected *index*, not the selected value. I almost got caught.

Answer (score 2):

It has been a long time since I've done VB, but here goes:

If you put the comboboxes in an array, you can use 1 handler for all

```
Protected Sub ComBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComBox_GER1.SelectedIndexChanged ComBox_GER2.SelectedIndexChanged ComBox_GER3.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim cb = CType(sender, ComboBox) 'cast to ComboBox
    Dim ValueSelected = cb.SelectedIndex

    For Each combo As ComboBox In comboboxes
        If Not combo Is cb And combo.SelectedIndex = ValueSelected Then
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
            combo.ClearSelection()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I did not declare comboboxes. Make an array, put each ComboBox you want to handle in there and you can then loop through them. I don't know about the ClearSelection

Comment: you didn't indent any of the code inside your `Sub` and you should,  I am going to edit this in because it is standard formatting for VB. and +1